# allow keyboard input based on regex or string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add an `allow` function for a keydown event. What is supposed to happen, is that you can pass it a `RegExp` or `string` of keyboard keys that you want to allow to be inserted into the input field, and everything else then gets rejected.

The issue I am having is with the else. Having it there is blocking every input. Removing the else allows for the `RegExp` to work, but then strings don't work.

What is causing this?

```js
function allow(evt, ...names) {
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    let name = names[i]
    if (name instanceof RegExp) {
      if (!name.test(evt.key)) {
        evt && evt.preventDefault()
      }
    } else {
      name = name.toString()
      if (name.toLowerCase() != evt.key.toLowerCase()) {
        evt && evt.preventDefault()
      }
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  allow(e, /\d/, 'Backspace')
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to restrict user to type in `input` box. In the example, you only need user to either type numbers or backspace.

The issue with your case is that both your condition will fire. If user types, say number 1 on keyboard, if condition evaluates, which is fine, but then you are looping through to Backspace (second name), which fails at the lowercase condition.

Try something like this:

```
const allow = (evt, ...names) => {
  const keys = names.filter(n => n.constructor !== RegExp)
  const regexs = names.filter(n => n.constructor === RegExp)
  const isInKeys = keys.filter(k => k.toLowerCase() === evt.key.toLowerCase())
  if (isInKeys.length === 0) {
    regexs.forEach(regex => {
      if (!regex.test(evt.key)) {
        evt && evt.preventDefault()
      }
    })
  }
}
```

You check if user has pressed a key that you allow, then no action is needed otherwise pass them through all the `regex`s.

HTH